# Qual a diferença entre npm e npx?

Tags: node.js, npm

Estou estudando react native e reparei que muitos lugares utilizam o comando:

```
npx react-native run-android
```

Por que eu não posso utilizar o seguinte comando?

```
npm react-native run-android
```

E qual a diferença de utilizar o `npx` ou direto o pacote, como no exemplo a seguir?

```
react-native run-android
```

Comment: npm serve para você gerenciar os pacotes, instalando localmente, globalmente ou removendo-os, o npx serve para você executar sem instalar, o comando `react-native run-android` só é possível após uma instalação global, ex.: `nps install -G packageName`

Comment: @DenisRudneideSouza poderia escrever uma resposta com mais detalhes, por favor? (:

Comment: npx é um outro programa que instala e executa um pacote NPM que possua um comando de CLI, dentro de um comando só. Se você tivesse pesquisado no google teria uma resposta bem completa.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## O que é NPX?

NPX é um executor de pacote NPM que torna realmente fácil instalar qualquer tipo de executável de Node.js que normalmente teria sido instalado usando NPM. Se o NPM é um gerenciador (manager) de pacotes, o NPX é um **executor**, por isso o X no final da sigla. O `X` vem de *e**X**ecutor*.

O NPX foi desenvolvido pela Kat Marcán, atualmente é mantido pelo NPM, que foi comprado recentemente pelo Github. O NPX é um binário que está presente no NPM desde a versão 5.2.

## Por que usar o NPX?

Existem várias maneiras de instalar pacotes do Node.js, você pode colocá-los localmente (local para o projeto) ou instalar globalmente (no ambiente do usuário).

Às vezes, em vez de usar um dos dois métodos de instalação acima, você pode apenas usar o pacote e pronto.

Às vezes, você pode querer apenas experimentar uma lista de pacotes, pois pode não saber exatamente o que precisa.

Nesses casos, em vez de instalar localmente ou globalmente, você pode ir direto para a execução desses pacotes com NPX.

## Como funciona?

Quando você executa um pacote usando NPX, ele procura o pacote no **registro local** e **global** e, em seguida, executa o pacote.

Se o pacote ainda não estiver instalado, o NPX **baixa os arquivos do pacote** e instala o pacote, mas apenas **armazenará os arquivos em cache em vez de salvá-los**, ou seja, contradizendo o que foi dito na outra resposta:

> já o npx ele irá usar o pacote sem precisar baixar em sua máquina,

Para usar NPX, você executaria um comando como este:

```
npx some-package
```

Uma ótima maneira de ver a rapidez com que o NPX funciona é criar um aplicativo de React usando:

```bash
$ npx create-react-app my-app
```

<sub>Obs: `create-react-app` não é recomendados ser usado, foi apenas um script de exemplo. Veja em: [Goodbye create-react-app](https://dev.to/ag2byte/create-react-app-is-officially-dead-h7o)</sub>

O comando acima irá gerar um *app react*, denominado `my-app`, no caminho em que o comando foi executado usando o pacote `create-react-app`. O NPX então:

1. Procura o pacote em seu ambiente localmente (`node_modules` do projeto).
2. Se não for encontrado, procura o pacote em seu sistema (`node_modules` global).
3. Se não for encontrado, o NPX baixa os arquivos e executa o comando para criar um novo *app react*, usando apenas aquela linha de comando.

Como mostrado acima, NPX não só busca no site do **npmjs**, como busca de dentro da `node_modules` do projeto também ou até mesmo na `node_modules` global antes de ir na Internet buscar os pacotes e executar.

No exemplo do React, ter o `react-native cli` ou `create-react-app` na máquina ocupa espaço e essas bibliotecas são atualizadas muito rápido, então não compensa ficar mantendo elas na máquina. O comando `create-react-app`, por exemplo, é feito uma vez e depois nunca mais, a menos que você comece outro projeto.

## Observação

Uma desvantagem do NPX é que ele precisa pesquisar os pacotes, estejam eles instalados ou não, antes de realmente executá-los. Todo aquele caminho que já mencionei (1, 2 e 3) é percorrido pelo script do NPX. Isso pode ser uma sobrecarga quando você precisa fazer as coisas muito rapidamente, principalmente se os pacotes devem ser procurados e/ou baixados para ai sim serem executados.

---

Fonte:

- [Conhecendo o NPX - Executor de Pacotes do NPM](https://blog.rocketseat.com.br/conhecendo-o-npx-executor-de-pacote-do-npm/)

Answer (score 26):

**npm** é o gerenciador de pacotes node, ele irá instalar na sua máquina um pacote para que você possa utiliza-lo em outros projetos sem precisar baixar novamente.

já o **npx** ele irá usar o pacote sem precisar baixar em sua máquina, sendo assim você irá instalar um pacote no seu projeto ou até mesmo usar esse pacote, sem baixar os arquivos em sua máquina.

**Para que o npx é util?**

- Já instalou algum pacote global e precisou usá-lo pouquíssimas vezes?
- Já teve problemas de incompatibilidade com pacotes globais por diferença de versões em múltiplos projetos?
- Já sentiu que sua máquina está poluída por diversos pacotes globais?

Quando você instala react-native em sua máquina e começa um projeto usando ele ao invés de NPX, você está usando a versão do react-native do pacote instalado em seu node_modules, já quando usa npx você usa um pacote na nuvem do node, então isso te da liberdade para usar até outras versões que não tem em sua máquina.

Comment: O `npm` só consegue gerenciar pacotes front-end? o.o

Comment: agora com o node atuando no backend, o NPM acronimo de Node package manager, acaba sendo um gerenciador de pacotes frontend e backend.

Comment: Pode crer, entendi. (: